# В чем ошибка?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброе время суток). Есть JS:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://app.app.local/json.json",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {

    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    var target = $('#list');
    $.each(json, function(key,value) {
        target.append('<div id="'+key+'" class="item item-avatar"> <h2>'+ value.name +'</h2> <p><i class="ion-pricetags"></i> '+ value.tag +' <i class="ion-clock"></i> <span data-livestamp="'+ value.date +'"></span></p> </div>');
      }
          )};     
     });
```

Почему то не работает, пишет ошибки в строчке 11, 12 (две последние), исправить не получается :(.

Comment: @misc, хоть и не по теме, но вам не кажется странным, что вы работаете с json, а в dataType указываете "text"? ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предпоследней строчке не хватает точки с запятой после круглой скобки и лишняя точка с запятой после фигурной скобки на этой же строчке.

Вместо `)};` нужно написать `);}`

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле [@VenZell](/users/13336/venzell) прав, `';'` там лишняя, что вызывает ошибку. Синтаксис объектов в js запрещает использовать `';'`, т.к. для перечисления должна использоваться `','` , кроме случаев, когда пара `ключ:значение` последняя в объекте.

```
{
  'a': 'b',
  'c': 'd'
}
```

Чтобы избежать таких опечаток используйте линтер, либо нормальную IDE.